# Hardcoded Text Issues

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on an application in eclipse emulator "Nexus one" and i'm trying to add buttons onto the format. When I add the buttons they are fine. When I add my own text into the button I get a hardcode warning. So I would carry on and add the "@string/" which gets rid of the errors/warnings, but the problem is that the "@string/" shows up as text on the button.

-So how do I make the buttons say just Profile and Calendar without errors and or the @string/

I have no idea on how to fix this. here is code and pictures:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/Profile"
    android:onClick="profile" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/Calendar" 
    android:onClick="calendar"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you define the strings with key "Profile" and "Calendar" in your strings.xml?

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why this got instantly thumbed down.

Comment: The reason it got probably downvoted is that this is a very basic mistake, one that reading pretty much every abitratry android tut would resolve - I guess SO sees itself more of an advanced Q&A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple remove `@string/` from your `android:text` attribute. Thus each button would look like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Profile"
    android:onClick="profile" />
```

`@string/my_string_name` is used to reference Strings defined in a strings.xml resource file.

The other (and the "proper") way to fix these errors is to define these strings in XML.
If you edit strings.xml and add lines such as `<string name="Profile">Profile</string>`, these errors will go away, and you will be on the way to having an app that is capable of being easily translated to other languages.